# Java Bean getter not returning values

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I am trying to design a simple java bean/xhtml setup for a homework assignment. The implementation seems simple enough, however I can not get GlassFish to pull the info from the java bean and display it in the HTML.

I wrote my code, and then created a war file and loaded that into GlassFish autodeploy.

Here is index.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
   <h:head>
      <title>System information</title>
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
      <h:form>
        <p>           
            This system's java version is #{properties.getJavaVersion}
        </p>
        <p>
        This sytem's OS Name is #{properties.getOsName}
        </p>
        <p>
        This System's OS version is #{properties.getOsVersion}
        </p>
     </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

Here is my properties.java file located in root/WEB-INF/classes/com/stansbury/

```
package com.stansbury;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean

public class Properties {

public String javaVersion;
public String osName;
public String osVersion;

public String getJavaVersion() {
    javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
    return javaVersion;
}

public String getOsName() {
    osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
    return osName;
}

public String getOsVersion() {
    osVersion = System.getProperty("os.version");
    return osVersion;
}

}
```

Here is my web.xml file located in root/WEB-INF/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   version="2.5">
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
 </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Last but not least my faces-config.xml file located root/META-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
</faces-config>
```

What I see on my screen is "The System's os name is" and then blank. It is the same for the other two values. I created a traditional application to ensure that System.getProperties was working on my computer. I also initialized the properties.VALUES with different strings, just to make sure. I have been banging my head on a wall for the past six hours on this one. Again, this all seems like it should make sense based off different tutorials, textbooks and youtube video's I have researched. Any insight would be great!

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong way to access the bean properties using [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html):

```
This system's java version is #{properties.getJavaVersion}
```

It should be

```
This system's java version is #{properties.javaVersion}
```

Since `getJavaVersion()` is the getter , hence EL will look for `javaVersion` property. Same applies to other fields. If you have a bean class :

```
public class Foo {
   int bar;

   public int getBar(){
     return bar;
   }
}
```

The `bar` property should be accessed as `#{bean.bar}`.

Comment: After trying to get some sleep, I decided to try a few

Comment: I applied these settings, but it still did not work. I decided to try a completely ready to go setup I used verbatim from the textbook author, which I packaged into a WAR file and loaded into Glassfish. Could it be how I package the files? I just type the command "jar csv getProperties.war ." command from the root directory. I did the same process for the package that came with the book. Neither one of war packages deploy correctly as none of the getters return anything. Could there be basic settings I need to configure on my host system.

Comment: I apologize, the command I use is: jar cvf getProperties.war .

Comment: I ended up downloading NetBeans and using that instead of Eclipse. Everything worked just fine. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You must use [EL language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html) in order to access beans fields.
That means that to invoke bean's getters you must use getter method but without standard prefix, which is get/is.
Therefore you should use in xhtml:

```
properties.javaVersion
properties.osName
properties.osVersion
```

Please note xhtml doesn't read values from the fields directly, it reads only getters methods.